# Intern js :How to return PageObject of the page from the function which opens it ?

Tags: javascript, promise, intern, pageobjects

I'm working on a UI automation project using `Intern js` . And I'm implementing it using `page object model` . I have a simple scenario where user enters credentials in login page and is navigated to welcome page. 
In my script i have a 'doLogin()'  function in `LoginPage` which is responsible for entering credentials  and clicking submit button. 
Now the problem is i want `doLogin()` to return `WelcomePage` and i'm unable to figure out the way to do this.

Heres my code setUp:

LoginPage.js

```
             define([],
                   function () {

                     function LoginPage(remote) {
                     this.remote = remote;

                  }

                 LoginPage.prototype = {
                    constructor: LoginPage,
                  // Login Page related Methods

                   doLogin: function(username,password){
                    this
                    .findById(json.locators.username).
                    .type(username).end()
                    .findById(json.locators.password)
                    .type(username).end()
                    .findByXpath(json.locators.sumit).click().end()
                    .sleep(1000).then(function(){
                     return welcomePage// this is not working
                    })
                 }
             };

            return LoginPage;
        });
```

WelcomePage.js

```
             define([],
              function () {

                 function WelcomePage(remote) {
                    this.remote = remote;

                  }

               WelcomePage.prototype = {
                    constructor: WelcomePage,

                   doSomething: function(){
               //welcome page related method
                }
             };

        return WelcomePage;
    });
```

Now what i actually want to achive is to do something like:

```
loginpage.doLogin(usrname,password).doSomething();
```

can somebody help on this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more flexible way to implement page objects is to make them groups of helper functions (like Leadfoot's `pollUntil`) rather than Command-like objects.

Using that model, your LoginPage object might look like:

```
define([], function () {
    return {
        doLogin: function (username, password) {
            return function () {
                return this.parent
                    .findById(json.locators.username).
                    .type(username).end()
                    .findById(json.locators.password)
                    .type(username).end()
                    .findByXpath(json.locators.sumit).click().end()
                    .sleep(1000).then(function(){
                        return welcomePage// this is not working
                    });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

WelcomePage might look like

```
define([], function () {
    return {
        doSomething: function () {
            return function () {
                return this.parent
                    // more stuff
            }
        }
    };
});
```

You can call `this.parent` in the returned function because when the helper function is called (as a Command `then` callback) it's context will be set to the Command that's calling it.

You would use them like

```
define([
    './WelcomePage',
    './LoginPage',
    // ...
], function (
    welcomePage,
    loginPage,
    // ...
) {
    // ...

    this.remote
        .get('some page')
        .then(loginPage.doLogin('username', 'password'))
        .then(welcomePage.doSomething())
        // other stuff

    // ...
});
```

Comment: but it gives `Cannot read property 'findById' of undefined` error

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing a more complete test case. Is your `doLogin` function (assuming you're doing something like the examples above) returning a function, or is it returning the stuff inside the function (`this.parent.findById...`)? It needs to return a function, and this function will be called by virtue of being a `then` callback.

Comment: I spent ages trying to make overly complicated examples work.. then this approach worked like a charm.. Thank you so much!